# json get largest number

Tags: php, json

I get this JSON after running query of particular customer sale history.

```
$output=
     [
          {
            "customerID": 52970,
            "sale": [
              {
                "item": "pencil",
              }
            ],
            "saleNumber": "25",
          },
          {
            "customerID": 52970,
            "sale": [
              {
                "item": "book",
              }
            ],
            "saleNumber": "26",

          },
          {
            "customerID": 52970,
            "sale": [
              {
                "item": "pen",
              }
            ],
            "saleNumber": "27",
          }
        ]
```

when it comes to retrieving data such as `customerID`, I json `decode($obj = json_decode($output))` and get the customerID as `$ID = $obj->{'customerID'};`

How to get the maximum saleNumber from this JSON

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could simply loop through the JSON and compare it. E.g.

```
$max = 0;
for($i = 0; $i < count($obj); $i++)
{
    if((int)$obj[$i]->{"saleNumber"} > (int)$max)
        $max = (int)$obj[$i]->{"saleNumber"};
}
// The max value should be in $max
```

**EDIT**
Also if saleNumber is the last element in the object, you shouldn't have a ','